# QueryEx web services issue

Tags: 2007, search, web-services

I am using Microsoft Search Server 2008 (based on SharePoint Server 2007) + C# + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + ASP.Net to develop a web application which invokes Search Server 2008 Web Services when a button in the html page is pressed.

I am using the following code to query content from Microsoft Search Server 2008. My question is how to display the search results from the DataSet retrieved? I did not find a very good sample from Google.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The string containing the keyword to use in the search
        string keywordString = "Microsoft";

        //The XML string containing the query request information 
        //for the Web service
        string qXMLString = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>" +
        "<Query><SupportedFormats><Format revision='1'>" +
        "urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format>" +
        "</SupportedFormats><Context><QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>" +
        keywordString + "</QueryText></Context></Query></QueryPacket>";

        SearchTest.QueryService queryService = new SearchTest.QueryService();
        queryService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        DataSet ds = queryService.QueryEx(qXMLString);
    }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add a DataGridView to your app and then bind to the DataSet like this:

```
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns( DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```